# Database Design - Conditional Null Values

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-structures

I have a `work_orders` entity, it can have child work orders, so there is a `parent_id` on the table. There are cases where the child order can be invoiced separately or with the parent. So I have another column called `bill_with_parent`.

Since that `bill_with_parent` column only ever applies to child work orders, I've been setting it to `NULL` for non child work orders, and if it's a child, it's either going to be `0` or `1`.

Is that the proper way to handle something like this?

Comment: Yes, looks OK to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's not necessarily 'wrong'. I'd get rid of the `null` and just allow `0` and `1`.  Of course for parents it's always going to be `0`, only a child could have both `1` or `0`.

When you allow a field to be `null` you forever have to add protection for the `null` case in all your queries, so I'd reserve using `null` for use only with foreign fields keys or places where there literally no valid value.

Comment: I think OP meant 0/1 for child based on certain business constraints. in which case parent have to be NULL.

Comment: Right, parents could always have `0` for that field, and that would have the same result. If that's better than using null, that would be fine.

Comment: @kenshin9 yes, if it doesn't create a bogus state and you can avoid null, Id go for it, or even add another state `-1` for the parent case, but I think from your example, just a 0 works with parents.

Comment: While I have no problem   using nulls for some things, yes this appears to be one where the null is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your time!