# Database design - How to handle conditional data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

This might seem to be a duplication for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467964/database-design-conditional-null-values), but I have checked it out and it doesn't answer my case.

**My case**:

Consider these two tables:

```
patients                           |     vaccines                
                                   |
id | name     | birthdate          |     id | name
---------------------------        |     ---------------
1  | John Doe | 1994-03-12         |     1  | Tetanus
---------------------------        |     ---------------
2  | Jane Doe | 1996-80-02         |     2  | Hepatitis A
```

And this pivot table

```
patient_vaccine

id | patient_id | vaccine_id | date_received | comment
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 1          | 2019-01-01    | Lorem ipsum dolor set
----------------------------------------------------------------
2  | 1          | 2          | 2019-01-12    | Lorem ipsum dolor set
----------------------------------------------------------------
3  | 2          | 1          | 2018-09-21    | Lorem ipsum dolor set
```

Obviously to say that a specific patient took a specific vaccine a new record would be inserted in the pivot table having the `patient_id` with the `vaccine_id` along with the additional data.

But I have a situation where if the patient is *under 18 years old*, there would be no `vaccine_id`, instead there would be a `took_all_vaccines` boolean.

**My question**:

What is considered better, put the under-18 patients data in a separate table that would look something like this:

```
id | patient_id | took_all_vaccines | date_received | comment
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 1                 | 2019-01-01    | Lorem ipsum dolor set
----------------------------------------------------------------
2  | 1          | 0                 | 2019-01-12    | Lorem ipsum dolor set
----------------------------------------------------------------
3  | 2          | 9                 | 2018-09-21    | Lorem ipsum dolor set
```

or should I put the put the `took_all_vaccines` column in the pivot table and make it nullable where it would be null for people over 18, which would also require to have the `vaccine_id` column to be nullable for people under 18.

so I would end up with something like this:

```
id | patient_id | vaccine_id | took_all_vaccines | date_received | comment
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 1          | null              | 2019-01-01    | Lorem ipsum dolor set
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | 1          | 2          | null              | 2019-01-12    | Lorem ipsum dolor set
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  | 2          | null       | 1                 | 2018-09-21    | Lorem ipsum dolor set
```

If one is solution is better, why? and why the other is not?

Comment: Just add an ID called injection_ID or something like that to the left of the table. Then when you select you can pull all of the injections and see what the vaccines were for a specific patient.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ that would take all the under-18-related columns and move them to another table, but I would still need the `vaccine_id` column to be null, which I think is not a good thing, especially that it is a foreign key.

Comment: "Took all vaccines" could become stale.

Comment: @KebabProgrammer  To indicate if the under-18 patient took all vaccines or not, there can't be a `vaccine_id` value in this case

Comment: I think you are better off using your second approach, because you can always update `vaccine_id` and `took_all_vaccines` based on the conditions of your program. If `vaccine_id` is set, then `took_all_vaccines` is null and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you are calling a Pivot table, in standard relational design is typically referred to as a Many-to-many resolver table.  This is because, at a high level your design involves a relationship between patient and Vaccines that is Many to many.

- A Patient can take many vaccines
- A vaccine can be taken by many Patients

**Now to your specific question:**

There is no perfect answer here, because this is a business rule that exists outside of the normal relations, but I would do one of 2 different things.

The first thing about Vaccines, is that AFAIK, multiple vaccines are often combined in one shot.  So this cries out for either a "shot" table, or the ability of the vaccine table to support a parent child hierarchy.

"Took all vaccines" seems to me to be a non-specific and factually inaccurate representation, but then again I don't know your application.

Given that, the simplest and best answer in my opinion, is to add a row in Vaccine named "All Vaccines (Patient under 18 years of age)".

Then you no longer need to concern yourself with NULL foreign keys, which you certainly don't want in a many-to-many resolution table.

The other alternative, would be to implement the shot container table (shot 1 -> Many vaccines) and have patient_shot replace patient_vaccine.  You could also do something similar by combining shot and vaccine into a single hierarchical table, where vaccines can have a parent "vaccine" row.

Comment: There's actually no standard term for the table in a many-to-many relationship. I've heard it called a bridge table, an intersection table, etc.

Comment: @BillKarwin Agree that nothing came from Codd on this, but it's fairly standard parlance in my experience with other DBA's, developers and architects.  The reason I brought it up, is that a Pivot table is something else entirely, related specifically either to excel or data warehousing.

Comment: So,yes..after a bit more research, there indeed is no perfect answer and this tends to be a more when-to-split-tables situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would not implement the flag or add 'Took all vaccines' as an entry into patient_vaccine table.

Reason:
Tomorrow you may decide to add a new vaccine and results for all patients that right now flagged as got all vaccines will be ruined. You will lose the track that they were not vaccinated with the newly added vaccine.